# Generalized Linear Mixed Model SPSS from F- to Likelihood Ratio Test

Tags: spss, mixed-models

I'm doing a generalized linear mixed model with SPSS. As I use poisson regression I would like to change the global test from F-Test to Likelihood Ratio Test or Chi-square test.

Does anyone know how i can put this into my syntax?

```
 /FIELDS TARGET=MmDWohlbefinden TRIALS=NONE OFFSET=NONE
  /TARGET_OPTIONS DISTRIBUTION=POISSON LINK=IDENTITY
  /FIXED  EFFECTS=Intervention Zeit BPSD Intervention*BPSD USE_INTERCEPT=TRUE
  /RANDOM EFFECTS=ID USE_INTERCEPT=FALSE COVARIANCE_TYPE=VARIANCE_COMPONENTS SOLUTION=FALSE
  /BUILD_OPTIONS TARGET_CATEGORY_ORDER=ASCENDING INPUTS_CATEGORY_ORDER=ASCENDING MAX_ITERATIONS=100 CONFIDENCE_LEVEL=95 DF_METHOD=RESIDUAL COVB=MODEL PCONVERGE=0.000001(ABSOLUTE) SCORING=0 SINGULAR=0.000000000001
  /EMMEANS_OPTIONS SCALE=ORIGINAL PADJUST=LSD.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option is not currently offered in GENLINMIXED. If you want to convert the F statistics to chi-squared statistics, multiply them by their numerator degrees of freedom and refer them to chi-squared distributions with df equal to that numerator df value. You can get p values using 1-CDF.CHISQ in a COMPUTE in SPSS Statistics.